# SQL: get all values from string when something occurs

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a SQL table where the `position` column is a long string, as shown below:

```
event| position
----------------------
  A  | {""type"":""dx"":502|;|""dy"":705|;|""type"":""dx"":647|;|""dy"":756|;|}
  B  | {""type"":""dx"":504|;|""dy"":842|;|""type"":""dx"":982|;|""dy"":457|;|""type"":""dx"":820|;|""dy"":547|;|}
```

`position` has information regarding the length and width (`dx` and `dy`) of each `event`. However, there are multiple `dx` and `dy` values, and they are more occurrences in the second row than in the first. I want to extract them all and average them.

So for `event` A, I want to  get the average of 502 and 647 for `dx` and the average of 705 and 756 for `dy`. For `event` B, I want to get the average of 
504, 982, and 820 for `dx` and the average of 842, 457, and 547 for `dy`. Below is what I want to get out. How can I get that?

```
event| mean_dx | mean_dy
------------------------
  A  |  575.5  | 730.5
  B  |  768.7  | 615.3
```

Comment: can you add your attempts to the question?

Comment: Your best option is fixing your table so that you have atomic data. Having delimited data is not a great practice.

Comment: I would love to fix the data but I'm not the one who generates the table!

Answer (score 1):

How uniform is your data?

Are the values always 3 digits?  Can they be between 2 and 4 digits?

You can use regex to parse the strings.  Either by looking for a numeric value and capturing it and the next two characters, or looking for a numeric and capturing everything between it and the next non-numeric.

Use a toggle to put odd(dx) values into a different collection than even(dy) values, then do your math for averaging.

Or put them all into the same collection and use a toggle to pull odd and even indexed values for your dx/dy average calculations.

It'll be a little wordy to write up front but the execution performance should be pretty good.

Conversely, I like @Error_2646's comment.  Take the time now to properly structure your database.  You should probably have a dx_lookup table and a dy_lookup table, comprised of an event id and the value.  Then you can just query for all the dx for event X and perform your average.

Edit:  If you already have data you need, but can also stop execution, you can use the same regex described above to parse your data and populate your lookup tables.

Comment: Data can be any number of digits. Will look into regex.